# Jquery input text change

Tags: javascript

Как в jquery отслеживать изменение `value=""` у `input` text в режиме реального времени? То есть как только изменился `value=""` вылетало окошечко `alert($(this).val());`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Лично я использую :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('selector').on('input', function(){ alert(' я не искал ответ в гугле :D ') })
 });
```

Но есть несколько способов, события `keyup`, `input`, `change`. Выбирайте что вам больше подходит.

В гугле это называется: jQuery event или JavaScript event ( события ).

Comment: ну и alert у вас)))

Answer (score 2):

Например:

```js
$('input').on('keyup',function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      val = $this.val();
  
  if(val.length >= 1){
    alert('изменился символ');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="n" id="n">
```